# Prevent hash change

Tags: html, flash, hashchange

I have a 3rd party flash object embedded in a webpage that changes the hash location when you click on it. I don't want it to do so and I don't have access to the flash source. Is there any way to prevent this flash object from changing the hash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the best thing you can do is overlay a transparent png over the flash movie to block the click event from entering the movie.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks for the confirmation.